# (Dis)aligning lyrics to a melody with LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, engraving, lyrics

I am trying to write a score for piano and voice. The piano actually has staves associated with it, but because the melody is already common and known by the intended audience, there is no staff for the voice, only lyrics. Problem is, I can't seem to (dis)align them how I want. In particular,

- when the piano should be played legato, Lilypond automatically holds the lyrics accordingly, which is not what I want;
- the beam #9 is also causing me troubles for the lyrics

For the correct legati / slurs and the correct beam #9, my .ly code is as follows :

```
%%%%%%%%%%
%% VERSION
%%%%%%%%%%

\version "2.20.0.3"


%%%%%%%%%
%% LYRICS
%%%%%%%%%

singerLyrics = \lyricmode {
    a b c |
    a b c |
    d e f |
    d e f |
    g h i j k |
    l m |
    g h i j k |
    l m |
    n o p q r |
    s |
    n o p q r |
    s |
}


%%%%%%%%%%%
%% PIANO UP
%%%%%%%%%%%

pianoUpper = \relative c' {
    \clef "treble"
    \key c \major
    \time 6/8

    <e g>8.( \p <f a>16 <e g>8 <c e>4.) | 
    <e g>8.( \pp <f a>16 <e g>8 <c e>4.) | 
    <f d'>4( \mf <f d'>8 <f b>4.) |
    <e c'>4( \p <e c'>8 <e g>4.) |
    <f a>4( \mf \< <f a>8 <a c>8. <g b>16 <f a>8) |

    <e g>8.( \> <f a>16 <e g>8 <c e>4.) |
    <f a>4( \< <f a>8 <a c>8. <g b>16 <f a>8) |
    <e g>8.( \> <f a>16 <e g>8 <c e>4.) |
    <f d'>4( \< <f d'>8 << { f'8. d16 <b f>8 } \\ { <g b>4 s8 } >> \! |
    <e c'>4.( <g e'>) |

    <e c'>8. \p g16 e8 <b g'>8. f'16 d8 |
    c4.~ \> c4 r8 \! \bar "|."
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% PIANO LOW
%%%%%%%%%%%%

pianoLower = \relative c {
    \clef "bass"
    \key c \major
    \time 6/8

    <c e g>4 <c e g>8 <c e g>4. |
    <c e g>4 <c e g>8 <c e g>4. |
    <g g'>4 <g g'>8 <g g'>4. |
    <c g'>4 <c g'>8 <c g'>4. |
    f8 <a c> <a c> f <a c> <a c> |

    c, <e g> <e g> c <e g> <e g> |
    f <a c> <a c> f <a c> <a c> |
    c, <e g> <e g> c <e g> <e g> |
    g, <f' g b> <f g b> g, <f' g b> <f g b> |
    c <e g c> <e g c> c <e g c> <e g c> |

    <g, e' g>4. <g f'> |
    <c e>4 g8 <c, c'>4 r8 \bar "|."
}


%%%%%%%%
%% SCORE
%%%%%%%%

\score {
    <<
        \new PianoStaff <<
        \new Staff = "upper" {\new Voice = "singer" \pianoUpper}
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto singer \singerLyrics
        \new Staff = "lower" \pianoLower
        >>
    >>
}
```

And the result is :

[image]

But if I have the correct lyrics alignment (and no legato, and my beam #9 is all wrong), it looks like :

[image]

In the LilyPond documentation, I find what I would need if I actually had a staff for the voice, but I don't. I can't seem to find how to do it.

Has anyone a solution for me?

Comment: use `\(` and `\)` instead of `(` and `)` for phrasing slurs

Comment: @ElementsinSpace thanks, that helps a lot! Now I just need a solution for beam #9.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by beam #9?

Comment: @Richard beam #9 is written like `<f d'>4 \( \< <f d'>8 << { f'8. d16 <b f>8 } \\ { <g b>4 s8 } >> \! \) |` and the entire `<< {} \\ {} >>` construction seems to be taken as one syllable for the lyrics. Someone has answered with a good answer that makes that problem irrelevant, though, so all's fine.

Comment: @Richard or did you ask what I call a beam? English is not my mother tongue, and I learnt music terminology in another language. For me, there are 12 beams in the images that I posted above, and they are separated by bars. Is that a beam? If not, how do you call them in English?

Comment: @Richard Ah, it's a bar or measure. Mmmh. I feel like a fool now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the simplest way of doing that is using a `NullVoice`. It's like a normal voice, but with the catch that it is never typeset anywhere.

So you add a NullVoice into one of your staves and fill it with some notes so that connecting the lyrics to this voice gives you the desired placement. Like this: http://lilybin.com/frt2h1/1 .

(This is also good when typesetting things for a choir. Sometimes you want to typeset only one line of lyrics for all voices, but each voice has some quirky places that would make the lyrics disalign.)

Comment: That is actually SUPER nifty! Thank you very much!